# Http post response after multiple new resource creation?

Tags: http, post, http-headers, httpresponse

I understand that 'a' server response to posting an enclosed entity where a new resource is created could be a 'created' plus a location header and a url.  That is my normal modus operandi.  However I just wrote some server code that, in addition to accepting a single enclosed thing and creating a new resource, also accepts a batch of stuff as an entity and creates multiple resources from it.

As an example, consider /cars.  You might post a single new car to make /cars/toyota-camry, or you might post multiple cars at once to result in /cars/toyota-camry, /cars/chevrolet-corvette, etc.

What is the proper response here, if any?

Comment: There is no right or wrong here. Implement what makes most sense for your task. Probably either a list of resources, maybe using json format, or you name the _set_ of resources, so a virtual directory maybe.

Comment: That sounds good.  I was fearing a "don't do that" response, or a "redesign your whole scheme so a batch of stuff is a single resource"  blah blah.

Comment: Some good responses here: [HTTP POST response Location header when creating multiple resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092787/http-post-response-location-header-when-creating-multiple-resources)