# HTTP POST response Location header when creating multiple resources

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes, restful-url, restful-architecture

The [HTTP/1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) states that if a `POST` operation results in the creation of a resource, then the response should include a `Location` header with the address of the new resource.

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header (see section 14.30).

and in section 14.30,

> For 201 (Created) responses, the Location is that of the new resource
>   which was created by the request.

Now suppose that my API allows batch creation of resources by `POST`ing an array to the collection resource URL. For example:

```
POST /books
[
    {
        "name": "The Colour of Magic",
        "published": "1983"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Light Fantastic",
        "published": "1986"
    }
]
```

Since two `\book\{bookId}` resources have been created, what should be the value of the `Location` header in this case?

The question [Http post response after multiple new resource creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128258) is similar, but it asks about the response entity, not the headers (and is unanswered).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this answer is late to the party but I believe the best solution is to create a new *"Batches"* resource with a uuid identifier that would return the list of Book URLs that were added using a URL like this:

```
http://api.example.com/batches/{uuid}
```

e.g.

```
http://api.example.com/batches/2b9b251f71a4b2901d66e04725bc0c9cb5843c74
```

Then your `POST` or `PUT` can return the above URL on it's `Location: {url}` header and a `201 - Created` status code.

If you then `GET` that URL that resource should respond with a representation that lists the URLs created in that batch, as well as any other info about the batch such as its uuid and the time/date it was created.

```
{
  "uuid": "2b9b251f71a4b2901d66e04725bc0c9cb5843c74",
  "datetime": "2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00",
  "books": [
    "http://api.example.com/books/the-colour-of-magic",
    "http://api.example.com/books/the-light-fantastic"
  ]
}
```

Those resources could then have a TTL of an hour or a month, whatever you choose. Or they could live forever if you want; whatever your use-case requires.

Comment: I think software should be signed to meet demand, not to meet standards. To me, this indicates a gap in the standards. I think returning the URL, without ID specification of the record(s) created makes sense. And then add the IDs as an array in de response.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk — Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I think should should be "signed"...?"

Answer (score 8):

RFC 2616 is obsolete. Stop looking at it except for historical purposes.

The current spec, RFC 7231, says:

"If one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a result of successfully processing a POST request, the origin server SHOULD send a 201 (Created) response containing a Location header field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created (Section 7.1.2) and a representation that describes the status of the request while referring to the new resource(s)." -- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#POST

And yes, that doesn't help a lot when there isn't a "primary" resource.

Comment: As you can see in my example, there is no "primary" resource - they are all peers. Not sure what to do in that case.

Comment: And thank you for the link to the new RFC ! Will have to bookmark it for reference.

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone has other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are in a particular use case for the header `Location`. In the case of bulk creation, the result of the processing is generally provided within the returned content itself. As a matter of fact, the processing can be completely or partially successful. I mean all elements were added or only a subset and the result shows to the end-user what actually happens.

So I think that the header `Location` isn't usable in such context. I see two options for the status code:

- The status code is **201** if at least one element is created)
- The status code is **200** to tell that the bulk request globally succeeds but the result of each operation is described in the response content.

You can however notice that a status code **202** exists if your resource handles the bulk creations in an asynchronous way. But in the context, you need then to pull a resource to get the status of the inserts.

Regarding the content of the response, you are free to choose. We could imagine something like that:

```
{
 "took": 4,
 "errors": true | false, 
 "items": [
  {  "added": true,
     "error": null
     "id": "123"
  },
  {  "added": false,
     "error": {
       "code": "err12",
       "description": "validation error (field type, ...)"
     }
     "id": null
  }
  ]
}
```

ElasticSearch provides such bulk api with create but also update and delete support - see this link for more details: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html.

Here are similar questions that could give some hints:

- [How to Update a REST Resource Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638071/how-to-update-a-rest-resource-collection)
- [REST API - Bulk Create or Update in single request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596688/rest-api-bulk-create-or-update-in-single-request)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry